# Twilio REST API to Flex

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Looking for a little guidance here.   The docs don't really cover this use case, so can someone please let me know if 1) this is possible, and 2) how to accomplish it?

Sequence:

REST Api to create a task

|

That task ends up as an incoming SMS in Twilio Flex

|

A worker accepts/responds via the Flex console

|

that message is sent to the user via text (SMS)

I've been testing in postman, and got it to the point where I can create a task, and it shows up in Flex, but it comes in as a default task with no sms component.

The docs are pretty thin regarding what the task creation fields can be, let alone what their values need to be.

```
Attributes = { "type" : "web", "to": "2024105613", "from" : "+14086871234", "queue" : "Everyone", "task-reason" : "service_request", "body" : "joel test" }
```

Please let me know if the use case / sequence I'm attempting is possible, and if so, do you have any pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**More info/clarification:**
What I'm hoping to do is have the worker see the incoming help request/task (that was sent in via the REST API) in Flex, and then respond in flex to the user which shows up on the user's device as a text message.

Right now, I can get the task to show up in flex, and I see the phone number that it "came" from, but I struggling with how I can have the worker respond via sms from the Flex portal.

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say that you create a Task via the API but the task ends up as an incoming SMS? Only incoming SMS messages will create tasks that are SMS messages. Do you want to create a generic task that allows an agent to start a conversation with a user over SMS?

Comment: yeah, that would work!  Essentially trying to pass up enough info in the task so that a worker knows what the user needs and can "reply"  (even if that reply starts an SMS conversation between the user and the worker).  What I'm hoping to do is have the worker see the incoming help request/task  (that was sent in via the REST API)  in Flex, and then respond in flex to the user which shows up on the user's device as a text message.  Let me know if that doesn't make sense  :)   Thanks!